# Can't access files in ZFS rpool /root directory in live recovery environment, but can access others outside /root

Tags: permissions, mount, root, luks, zfs

my Ubuntu installation fails to boot. Things hang after entering the encryption key with message `WARNING: Pool 'rpool' has encountered an uncorrectable I/O failure and has been suspended.` When I boot to the Ubuntu live installation environment on USB, I'm able to see rpool and bpool, and both are labeled healthy. I'm able to mount `zpool import` both, and can mount them just fine. The command I use is `mount -o zfsutil -t zfs rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_homof2 /path/to/mount/to`. I have successfully mounted the drive in read-only mode and read-write mode.

I'm trying to access files in `/root` within the mount (e.g. `/path/to/mount/to/root`). I'm able to access and copy (to an external drive) the files in every other directory (e.g. `/path/to/mount/to/var`, but not able to see anything within `/path/to/mount/to/root`. **Can someone help me access those files?**

*(Within `/root`, I stored the encryption keys to my other drives. I deserve all the shame for not backing those up elsewhere and making this easy.)*